# equation of ellipse after projection

Tags: analysis

If I have the intersection of $x+z=1$ and $$x^2 +y^2 +z^2=1$$ which is a circle in $O'xyz$. Then I do a projection of this circle on the $O'xy$ plane, it'll be an ellipse. How can I then find the equation of this ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intersection of the plane and the sphere is:
$$
\begin{cases}x+z=1\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
that, substituting $z$ from the first equation in the second, becomes:
$$
\begin{cases}z=1-x\\
2x^2+y^2-2x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Here there is the answer to the question.

The system is the ''equation'' of the circle of intersection.

The second equation, interpreted, as an equation in $3$D space (so that $z$ can have any real value), is the equation of a cylinder that pass through the circle anf has axis parallel to $z$ axis. Interpreted as an equation in the $xy$ plane it is the equation of the searched ellipse.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the circle, then $(x,y,z)$ satisfy both $x+z=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. It's equations are

$$\begin{cases} z=1-x \\ x^2+y^2+(1-x)^2=1\end{cases}$$

Its projection has $z$-coordinate equals $0$ and keep the $x$ and $y$-coordinates. So the equation of the projection on the $xy$-plane is

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+(1-x)^2&=1\\
2x^2+y^2-2x&=0
\end{align}

---

Another way to think of the problem.

The centre $C$ of the circle is a point on the plane $x+z=0$. The line joining $C$ and the origin is orthogonal to the plane. It is easy to see that $\displaystyle C=\left(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. $C$ is $\displaystyle  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ unit from the origin. So the radius of the circle is $\displaystyle\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

The projection of the circle is an ellipse with centre $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2},0,0\right)$. The major axis of the ellipse is parallel to the $y$-axis, which has the same length as the radius of the circle ($\displaystyle =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$). As the plane makes a $45^\circ$ with the $xy$-plane, the minor axis has length $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos45^\circ=\frac{1}{2}$, and it is parallel to the $x$ axis. The equation of the ellipse is

\begin{align}
\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}{(\frac{1}{2})^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2}&=1\\
(2x-1)^2+2y^2&=1
\end{align}